# Buttons in GridLayout, non resize

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have problems with `GridLayout` because I understand that I need this only for solving my problem: I need this matrix panel (made in `GridLayout`) to be non resizable. Like a whole square that is, for example, in the middle and can not be resized. I have made a lot of research work and I couldn't find an answer.

```
public class  ButtonsMatrix extends JButton {

    private int[][] fModel;
    private  int fX;
    private  int fY;

    public ButtonsMatrix(int x, int y, int[][] model) {

        fX = x;
        fY = y;
        fModel = model;

        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fModel[fX][fY] = fModel[fX][fY] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
                updateNameFromModel();
            }
        });
        updateNameFromModel();
    }

    private void updateNameFromModel() {
        setText(String.valueOf(fModel[fX][fY]));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dim=10;
        int matrix[][] = new int[10][10];

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Window containing a matrix");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JPanel extra = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        extra.add(p);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(dim, dim));

        for (int r = 0; r < dim; r++){
            for (int c = 0; c < dim; c++){
                ButtonsMatrix button= new ButtonsMatrix(r, c, matrix);
                p.add(button);
            }
        }

        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the panel with a `GridLayout` inside another panel that has a **`GridBagLayout`**.

If it's the only component and is added with no `GridBagConstraints`, it will be centered and its size will be constant irrespective of the size assigned to the panel with grid bag layout.

### Edit

The above code adds the panel containing a grid layout of buttons to the `extra` panel defined in the main method (which has a `FlowLayout`). This will **also** work to keep the button matrix panel at its preferred size.

The problem with the code is that it thereafter ignores the `extra` panel and adds the `p` panel (with the grid layout of buttons) directly to a `JFrame` with a (default) `BorderLayout`. Doing so results in the `p` panel being added to the `CENTER` of the border layout, which will stretch a component to fill the available width and height.

To fix that, simply change:

```
f.add(p);
```

To:

```
f.add(extra);
```